# NLog GetCurrentClassLogger slow-running method warning: Overstated?

Tags: logging, nlog

NLog mentions this comment about "slow-running", and I've seen others repeat this as a warning... as though you should avoid using `GetCurrentClassLogger()` when using NLog.

My question is this: If you are using a NLog as suggested, from a static field, is this warning overstated?  Wouldn't it run just once per type... not once per `new`?

Extra credit: If that's true, what would it take to make a static field initialize repeatedly, in order to make this warning valid?

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Gets the logger with the name of the current class.  
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The logger.</returns>
/// <remarks>This is a slow-running method. 
/// Make sure you're not doing this in a loop.</remarks>
[CLSCompliant(false)]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public static Logger GetCurrentClassLogger()
{
    return factory.GetLogger(GetClassFullName());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NLog mentions this comment about "slow-running", and I've seen others repeat this as a warning... as though you should avoid using `GetCurrentClassLogger()` when using NLog.

The slow running part of `GetCurrentClassLogger` is the [`GetClassFullName` method](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/119cd8045f6500671e35e05996aaa4e7165f8302/src/NLog/LogManager.cs#L379) which scans the `StackTrace` for the current class name. This isn't really slow, but also not fast so it would be a waste to re-scan the `StackTrace` by calling  `GetCurrentClassLogger` in a loop. To be clear, if the performance of NLog is really important, `LogManager.GetLogger("your class name")` is always faster.

In general there is no performance impact when using  `GetCurrentClassLogger` in your class, even if isn't `static`. For performance reasons it is recommend to assign it to a static field.

> My question is this: If you are using a NLog as suggested, from a static field, is this warning overstated?  Wouldn't it run just once per type... not once per `new`?

TL;DR: yes, you can ignore this warning when using a `static` field. The "slow part" indeed runs only once for each type.

> Extra credit: If that's true, what would it take to make a static field initialize repeatedly, in order to make this warning valid?

Just **don't** do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
    LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Trace("some cool trace");
}
```